# Memory leak because of seemingly necessary malloc repetition

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have the following structures:

```c
typedef struct pair {
  int *key;                // search key for this item
  int *count;                  // pointer to data for this item
  struct pair *next;   // children
} pair_t;

typedef struct counters {
  struct pair *head;
} counters_t;
```

I have the following function:

```c
static pair_t * // not visible outside this file
pair_new(const int key)
{

  pair_t *pair = malloc(sizeof(pair_t));

  free(pair->key);
  free(pair->count);

  if (pair == NULL) {
    // error allocating memory for pair; return error
    return NULL;
  } else {

      pair->key = malloc(sizeof(int));
      pair->count = malloc(sizeof(int));

      *(pair->key) = key;
      *(pair->count) = 1;
      pair->next = NULL;
      return pair;

  }
}
```

notice that I allocate for a pair at first, check if the memory was properly allocated, and then if so I assign values to the elements of the instance of pair. In order to assign values to these elements (key and count) I have to allocate memory for them (the elements). Later on in my main program I call the delete function:

(ctrs is a linked list of pairs)

```c
void counters_delete(counters_t *ctrs){
  if(ctrs!=NULL){
    pair_t *temp = ctrs->head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
      printf("freeing for key %d\n",*(temp->key));
      free(temp->count);
      free(temp->key);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    ctrs->head=NULL;
  }
  return;
}
```

in which i free each pair's key and count.

because i allocated for the full size of a pair and then allocated again for the elements for each pair, i am left with memory that has not been freed at the end of the program. how can i fix this?

Comment: why there are `free(pair->key);
  free(pair->count);` after the malloc?

Comment: ^^^^^^ ... which invokes undefined behavior, as those pointers are indeterminate.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right sir, converted that to an answer already. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh.. which has already been upticked =)

Comment: is there any reason for not making `key` and `count` simply `int`s ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're making a great deal of trouble for yourself by making `pair_t.key` and `pair_t.count` be pointers.  You don't seem to be doing anything with them that benefits from the indirection, yet you need to do extra work to manage the associated memory.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, remove

```
free(pair->key);
free(pair->count);
```

after `malloc()`, as calling `free()` on the pointers not returned by memory management functions invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, in the beginning, you `malloc()`-ed for the original variable and the members, and in the end, you are freeing only the pointer members `key` and `count` of the structure variable, but the actual variable `temp` remains allocated. This is what causing the leak.

You have to free the `temp`, too.

Comment: "The variable `temp` remains allocated" is ***wrong***. The *node* remains allocated. This has nothing to do with variables.

Comment: @immibis I mentioned that in the context of the complete sentence. Why you are quoting only half of it?

Answer (score 2):

> ... i am left with memory that has not been freed at the end of the program. how can i fix this?

You'll have to make a copy of `temp` before moving on to the next element and then free the element after you have moved `temp`to the next element.

```
pair_t *temp2 = temp;   // Add this before
temp = temp->next;
free(temp2);            // Add this after
```

Also see the answer from Sourav Ghosh about removing the illegal calls to `free`